# If $B\subset A$ and $f:A\to B$ is injective prove it's a bijection between $A$ and $B$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

I want to show that if $B\subset A$ and $f:A\to B$ is an injective function then there's a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

---

I believe my "proof" is wrong, I probably use too much "intuition" when I try to solve it. But hopefully I will get a better feeling if someone tells me where/what I do wrong and help me. :) That said, a friend to me "solved" another problem

"if $f:A\to C$ is an injective function, and $g:C\to A$ is an injective function, then there is a bijection between $A$ and $C$".

She argued like this " for all $a$ in $A$ we can find an element $f(a)$ in $C$ and for all $c$ in $C$ we have an element $g(c)$ in $A$. If f(a)=c then we must have g(c)=a. This holds for all $a$ and $c$. So each $a$ maps to exactly one $c$ and each $c$ maps to exactly one $a$".

That is the Schröder–Bernstein theorem though, I have seen the proof, so I could directly tell that it's a wrong proof. I would probably not argue in the exactly same way but probably in a similar fashion. On the other hand I cannot really tell why this doesn't prove the fact either. Oh well, here comes my proof, it's a similar argument so I guess I'm wrong :)

**Proof:**

Since I already know it's injective, I just have to show it's surjective. We have that $B\subset A$, that is, every element of $B$ is in $A$. Because of this we can for every element $b\in B$ find an element $a\in A$ such that $b=f(a)$. That is, $\forall b\in B\exists a\in A:\textbf{ }b=f(a)$. But that is the definition of surjection. Hence, there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$ since f is injective.

I bet I've forgot to mention something now, which I found important to mention, but unfortunately I have forgotten it. Hopefully I will remind myself. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: As said ny @mfl, what you tried to show is wrong. However, if $B\subseteq A$ and $f:A\rightarrow B$ is injective, you can show that *there is* a bijective function $g:A\rightarrow B$. This can be done with a cardinality argument.

Comment: You can use the Schröder–Bernstein theorem since if $B\subset A$ then $g:B\to A$ as the identity $g(b)=b$ is an injective function and you know    from the question $f:A\to B$ is an injective function. But your friend's proof of the Schröder–Bernstein theorem looks wrong, as does your proof for this question

Comment: I think there is some confusion on what you want to prove: what you try to prove at the end is far stronger (and somehow false) than what you ask in the beginning, which again is slightly different from what's written in the title. In the last part you try to prove that $f$ is surjective... which is true if and only if the subset $B$ you chose **arbitrarily** is the image of $f$. Pick any injection $f$ mapping $A$ onto a proper subset of $A$. Then, $B=A$ is a counterexample.

Comment: It would be good if $A$ were finite. Alas, for infinite sets the argument fails.

Comment: With a finite set B has to equal A:  An injection "forces" the mapped to set to be at least as big as the injecting set.  So in a finite set f:A->B $\subset$ A forces B = A.  In infinite sets you can always have proper subsets of equal cardinality and subsets proper subsets between.  $f(A) \subset B \subset A$ all proper is always possible. @egreg

Comment: @fleablood Ah thanks mate, a comment I needed to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't hold that $f$ gives the bijection. Consider $A=(0,2),B=(0,1)$ and $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{3}.$

The problem in your proof: Each element of $B$ is an element of $A,$ but this doesn't mean that an element of $B$ has a preimage. Think of the above example.

Comment: Perhaps make $A=(0,3)$? The example, as it is, doesn't satisfy $B\subset A$.

Comment: @yurnero Thank you for noticing it. I have changed the roles of $A$ and $B.$

Answer (score 1):

Just argue like this:
$B\subset A$ gives an injection $i:B \rightarrow A$ (the standard inclusion: every $b \in B$ is sent to itself). By hp, you are given $f: A \rightarrow B$ injective, so that by Cantor-Berstein you know $A$ and $B$ are in bijection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your friend is wrong.  $f(a)$ maps to exactly one $c$ and $g(c)$ maps to exactly one $b \in A$ but there is no reason in any of the pluperfect hells to assume that $b$ is the same as the original $a$.

Anyway you comment isn't true.  Let $f: (0,1) \rightarrow (0,1/2)$ $f(x) = \frac 1 4 x$.  There is no $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x) = 1/3$.

Of course if the statement was $f: A \rightarrow f(A) \subset A$.... that'd be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Just because $A \subset B$ doesn't necessarily mean that $\forall b \in B \exists a \in A \colon b = f(a)$; for instance: $f \colon \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N*, f(x) = 2 \times x + 1$. $ \mathbb N* \subset \mathbb N$. The function is injective, but there exists $b$ such that $ \nexists a \in A \colon b = f(a)$, for instance $b = 0$. That's the problem with the proof(essentially, you implicitly assumed that the function is surjective). A simpler proof would be: let $g \colon B \rightarrow A$ so that $g(x) = x$. The function is obviously injective. Therefore we have both $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ and $g \colon B \rightarrow A$, both injective. Therefore, by the Schröder–Bernstein theorem, there must exist a bijection between $A$ and $B$.